# Why am I not able to connect to my database?

Tags: php, sql, database, connection

I am having some problems trying to connect to my database.
I have used the following code:

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Playlists</title>
  <meta name="description" content="test">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets.css">

  </head>

<body>
      <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.samsung.com/us/showcase/milk/img/meta-fb-milk-music.png" alt="Home"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="playlist.html">Playlists</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<div class="content">
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("not fire" . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "fire";

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

mysql_close();

?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Of course these are not my real login names, but these are definitely right.
When I open the page it says: "fireUnable to select database" So the connection with the server is going okay, but the connection to the database isn't. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Because you are mixing `mysqli with mysql` at `mysql_select_db` here

Comment: Should I change it to mysqli or mysql? I have tried this: // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("not fire" . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "fire";

@mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

mysqli_close();

But then I get the same error.

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

You missed the Database Name in your Connection. You are Using the Object Oriented Style, remember? Try this instead:

```
    <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Playlists</title>
        <meta name="description" content="test">
        <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets.css">

    </head>

    <body>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.samsung.com/us/showcase/milk/img/meta-fb-milk-music.png" alt="Home"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="playlist.html">Playlists</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
        <?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username   = "username";
            $password   = "password";
            $database   = "dbname";

            // Create connection

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);


            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("not fire: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 
            echo "fire";

        ?>


    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```